# Compound function in ML

Tags: ml, infix-notation

I need to write a function compound in ML that will behave as follows:

Compound takes in a bin op f, and an int n, and a value x, and it applies the operator to x N times. Here is an example:

```
compound f 0 x = x
compound f 1 x = x f x
```

I am a newbie at ML so I have trouble understanding how to write this function. I will greatly appreciate any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to write a function that is simplified version of [`foldl`](http://www.standardml.org/Basis/list.html#SIG%3aLIST.foldl%3aVAL) or [`foldr`](http://www.standardml.org/Basis/list.html#SIG%3aLIST.foldr%3aVAL), depending on `f` associativity. But, since you missed parenthesis in your examples, I suppose `f` is right associative.

The code will be for your `foldr` case:

```
fun compound f x 0 = x
  | compound f x n = f(x, compound f x (n-1));
```